# How to achieve sub collection on a collection of an array?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to get the detailed product of a collection from `groupBy` in laravel. How can I achieve that?

I'm using php 7.1 and Laravel. I can get the collection for the total report for year, month, and day.
But can I get detailed product of that collection ?

My query for getting the collection in the controller

```
$totalBelanjaTahun   = DB::table('assets')
            ->select(DB::raw('EXTRACT(MONTH FROM belitanggal_assets) AS monthCoba, SUM(beliharga_assets) AS harga_beli'))
            ->where('belitanggal_assets', 'like', '%'.$tahun.'%')
            ->groupBy(DB::raw('monthCoba'))
            ->get();

    return view('DilarangBuka.reportTotalBelanjaTahun', compact('totalBelanjaTahun', 'tahun', 'totalPertahun'));
```

How can I achieve get detailed of product of that array, not just get the date and the price?  Thanks

Comment: If you want all the details for every member of the group, then `GROUP BY` is not going to work for you. With `GROUP BY` you get one record for all the combined items in the group. To get data on each item, you will have to get all the data back and then group the results by month or whatever in your code. Alternately, you could get the summary data the way you are now, and then run another query for the particular items you are interested in getting more data on.

Comment: could you please show me how to do that please ? this th reuslt of my query above 
https://ibb.co/9TSxH0q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't `groupBy` records in mysql, you will get first record of every groups.
Try to get them out.

```php
$totalBelanjaTahun   = DB::table('assets')
            ->select(DB::raw('EXTRACT(MONTH FROM belitanggal_assets) AS monthCoba, beliharga_assets AS harga_beli, field1, field2, field3'))
            ->where('belitanggal_assets', 'like', '%'.$tahun.'%')
            ->get();
```

And groups them by `collect`

```php
collect($totalBelanjaTahun)->groupBy('monthCoba')
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: thank you, but could you show me how the best way to pass it to blade view ? maybe in a table

Comment: something like this: ```$monCbs = collect($totalBelanjaTahun)->groupBy('monthCoba')->toarray()``` and in your blade view: ```@foreach ($monCbs as $monthCoba => $items)
    @foreach($items as $item) {{$item}}  @endforeach
@endforeach```